# Python script for searching on Facebook ads using Pipenv

Tags: python, facebook, api

I want to run a Python script on Facebook ads search, but I get stuck in the middle, hoping you can help me (please see below). For your information, I do have a Facebook API token, but it seems I have a problem running Pipenv.

https://github.com/pandringa/fb-ads-tool

I will appreciate any feedback you provide!

```
import csv
import re
import argparse
import dateparser
In [8]:

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Aggregates search results by key')
parser.add_argument('file')
parser.add_argument('-k', '--key')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--out')
Out[8]:
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-o', '--out'], dest='out', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
In [9]:

args = parser.parse_args()
infile = csv.DictReader(open(args.file))
usage: Aggregates search results by key [-h] [-k KEY] [-o OUT] file
Aggregates search results by key: error: unrecognized arguments: -f
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2


c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3339: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
In [10]:

rowset = {}
real_rowset = set()
In [11]:

out = csv.DictWriter(open(args.out, 'w'), fieldnames=[*infile.fieldnames, 'ad_versions_count'])
out.writeheader()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-4d5c0f933f42> in <module>
----> 1 out = csv.DictWriter(open(args.out, 'w'), fieldnames=[*infile.fieldnames, 'ad_versions_count'])
      2 out.writeheader()

NameError: name 'args' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are facing here is not related to `Pipenv`, it's related to the flow of your code, you probably ran the cells using `args` before defining it

I prefer to ran code like this in a script which I did with yours

```
import argparse
import csv

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Aggregates search results by key')
parser.add_argument('file')
parser.add_argument('-k', '--key')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--out')

args = parser.parse_args()
infile = csv.DictReader(open(args.file))


rowset = {}
real_rowset = set()

out = csv.DictWriter(open(args.out, 'w'), fieldnames=[*infile.fieldnames, 'ad_versions_count'])
out.writeheader()
```

Running it with the command

```
python your_code.py --k key --o ./file.csv  ./sample.csv
```

it actually works perfectly and yield an output csv with the same columns as the input one.
if you want to work with something like `Jupyter` or `ipython` then you do not need to use arg parser as you are not running python files with arguments, they are just cells executed in certain sequence.
I don't think that is your end goal here but that what your code do for now, hope this helps and ready to provide more support related to `fbads sdk` or `pipenv` if needed